# How do I turn a list into a string so I can save it in a txt file?

Tags: python, string, list

I tried some solutions from the internet but every time I get an error:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not function
```

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint
# from datetime import datetime
 
def createParamsByUser(amount, typeOfAnimal):
    params = { "amount" : amount, "animal_type" : typeOfAnimal}
 
    return params
 
def listToStr(s):
    str1 = ""
    return (str1.join(s))
 
typeOfAnimal = input("Would you read facts about cat or dog?\n")
amount = str(input("How many facts would you generate?\n"))
createdParams = createParamsByUser(amount, typeOfAnimal)
r = requests.get("https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts/random", createdParams)
s = []
try:
    content = r.json()
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
    print("Wrong format")
else:
    for animal in content:
        pprint(animal["text"])
        s.append(animal["text"])
 
printInToFile = input("Do you want print text above in to a file (type Y/N)")
 
if (printInToFile == "y" or "Y"):
    with open("Facts about",  "a+", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
        file.write(listToStr)
elif (printInToFile == "n" or "N"):
    print("Thanks for using my program")
```

By the way, how to write code to write datetime.today in front of the file name using datetime.today? I tried this:

```
with open(datetime.today + "Fact about" + typeOfAnimal , "a+", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
```

Comment: change `datetime.today` to `datetime.date.today()` I'd do the whole thing as `f'{datetime.date.today()} Fact about {typeOfAnimal}'`

Comment: Most of your code is irrelevant to the question. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. `listToStr` is a function. To get the returned string you need to call it: `listToStr()`

Comment: @MarkM `listToStr` needs to be called with a parameter, e.g. `listToStr(s)`

Comment: The code that you claim produces the error doesn't exist anywhere in your actual code?

Comment: @SuperStormer It's the third line from the end.

Comment: `printInToFile == "y" or "Y"` is not doing what you think it is.  This expression will always be True, because "Y" has a truthy value of True, and it doesn't matter what the value of `printlnToFile` is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this part:

```
if (printInToFile == "y" or "Y"):
    with open("Facts about",  "a+", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
        file.write(listToStr)
elif (printInToFile == "n" or "N"):
    print("Thanks for using my program")
```

In the `write()` function, you are giving `listTostr` as the argument, which is  a function object, replace that with `listToStr(<whatever parameters>)`.

```
if (printInToFile == "y" or "Y"):
    with open("Facts about",  "a+", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
        file.write(listToStr(parameters))
elif (printInToFile == "n" or "N"):
    print("Thanks for using my program")
```